# Qt4 OpenGL: QMPwidget building errors

Tags: opengl, qt4, widget, mplayer

I am trying to build QMPwidget. It is a widget that allows Qt developers to embed an MPlayer instance into their application for convenient video playback. I have downloaded the source files from [here](http://qmpwidget.sourceforge.net/). I have selected "Snapshot of the master branch" file from downloads. When try to build it with Qt Creator I am getting these errors:

```
qmpwidget.cpp:147: error: 'glClearDepth' was not declared in this scope
qmpwidget.cpp:158: error: 'glLoadIdentity' was not declared in this scope
qmpwidget.cpp:166: error: 'GL_QUADS' was not declared in this scope
qmpwidget.cpp:166: error: 'glBegin' was not declared in this scope
qmpwidget.cpp:167: error: 'glTexCoord2f' was not declared in this scope
qmpwidget.cpp:167: error: 'glVertex2f' was not declared in this scope
qmpwidget.cpp:171: error: 'glEnd' was not declared in this scope
```

Here are the pro and pri files of the project:

**src.pro:**

```
TEMPLATE = lib
DESTDIR = ..
TARGET = qmpwidget
QT += network opengl
CONFIG += staticlib

# Optional features
QT += opengl
CONFIG += pipemode

include(qmpwidget.pri)
```

**qmpwidget.pri**

```
HEADERS += \
    qmpwidget.h

SOURCES += \
    qmpwidget.cpp

!win32:pipemode: {
DEFINES += QMP_USE_YUVPIPE
HEADERS += qmpyuvreader.h
}
```

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: I am building on Ubuntu 10.10 x86 with Angstrom tool chain.

Comment: you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) toolchain? Errors you get happen because qmpwidget.cpp doesn't include <GL/gl.h> try including this file manually

Comment: Yes I have used that tool-chain.
GL headers included by qt classes.
I have copied project files into 3rdparty folder under src and compiled the project with Qt. Now it is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile QMPwidget, copy project files into 3rdparty folder under src and compile it with Qt